Update with keyword as user with Reference Field in Query
I'm trying to use the new keyword 'as user' for update, but I've notice that the update failed if query records contains fields from reference fields.
To verify the result I created two custom objects in Master-Detail relation (Parent_Object__c, Child_Object__c) and on the child a lookup field to the Account.
The following update failed:
//1.Query field from the M-D relation
Child_Object__c  childRecord = [    SELECT Id,Parent_Object__r.Name FROM Child_Object__c LIMIT 1];
update as user childRecord;        
//System.DmlException: Operation failed due to fields being inaccessible on Sobject Child_Object__c, check errors on Exception or Result! ) 
//->the parent field is not acceissble



//2.Query field from lookup relation
Child_Object__c childRecord = [SELECT Id, Account__r.Name FROM Child_Object__c limit 1];
update as user childRecord;
//System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0Y6900000ezgs9EAA; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference Account__r and a salesforce id, Account__c: []

I can overcome such failure by updating the record without the references, such as
Child_Object__c childRecord = [SELECT Id, Account__r.Name FROM Child_Object__c limit 1];
update as user new Child_Object__c(Id = childRecord.Id);

But that seems redundant work and lots of refactoring for existing code.
I couldn't find report for similar issues so I'm not sure if it is a Salesforce bug or it is work as design.
Does anyone encounter similar issue and perhaps have better solution?
